# JSF datatable with paging and sorting and browser-back

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, back-button

We are using Primefaces datatable component with sorting, pagination and a `LazyDataModel` in order to display search results. The backing bean of the search page is `ViewScoped`.

From the search result list a user can select a result item in order to view the details. This is implemented as a new page request, e.g.  `<h:link value="Show Details" outcome="showDetails?id=11234"/>`. By clicking the browser back button the user will navigate back to the search result list.

The problem is that the datatable will be in initial state again, so it wont display the last selected sort order and page. This is the case in most browsers, only Firefox 11 seems to keep those DOM changes in cache. Neither IE nor Chrome.

Does anybody has a good approach how to handle this? We actually don't need "ajaxified" sorting and paging. We would prefer handling everything through ViewParams, but this seems not to be supported by primefaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this as well, and I developed a coding pattern that might help.  It isn't really a PrimeFaces thing (which I am using as well) -- more of a technique for using book-markable links with JSF 2.

In the markup, I include all the parameters for the page as follows:

```
        <f:metadata>
            <f:viewParam name="orderID" value="#{bean.orderID}" />
            <f:viewParam name="sortMode" value="#{bean.sortMode}" />
            <f:viewParam name="firstRecord" value="#{bean.firstRecord}" />
            <f:viewParam name="pageSize" value="#{bean.pageSize}" />
        </f:metadata>
```

Each of those values is backed in the backing bean such that, if they are not set, they produce a suitable default value.  For example:

```
public int getPageSize() {
    if (pageSize < MIN_PAGE_SIZE) pageSize = DEF_PAGE_SIZE;
    if (pageSize > MAX_PAGE_SIZE) pageSize = DEF_PAGE_SIZE;
    return pageSize;
}
```

A link to this view can be generated as follows:

Now you implement user controls to change those values, and regenerate the table each time they are changed.  You should still use AJAX for that -- for example:

```
<p:spinner value=#{bean.pageSize} >
    <p:ajax update="tableID" />
</p:spinner>
```

In the setter methods, you have to trigger the re-generation of the table, but that's the gist of it.  I hope this helps.

UPDATE:

To handle pagination, you simply need to add links for first page, prior page, next page, etc.  The links will look something like this:

```
 <h:link  value="First Page" outcome="thisPage">
         <f:param name="orderID" value="#{bean.orderID}" />
         <f:param name="sortMode" value="#{bean.sortMode}" />
         <f:param name="firstRecord" value="0" />
         <f:param name="pageSize" value="#{bean.pageSize}" />
 </h:link>
 <h:link  value="Next Page" outcome="thisPage">
         <f:param name="orderID" value="#{bean.orderID}" />
         <f:param name="sortMode" value="#{bean.sortMode}" />
         <f:param name="firstRecord" value="#{bean.nextRecord}" />
         <f:param name="pageSize" value="#{bean.pageSize}" />
 </h:link>
```

etc.  You need to implement properties in the backing bean to calculate what the **firstRecord** param ought to be.

Comment: thx, yes having page and sort parameters as view params is what i prefer over ajax. but my question is more about how to handle pagination and sorting with this approach using a layz load datable in primefaces.

Comment: still - how do you tell the paginator and sorting buttons in primefaces datatable that they should not perform an ajax request but invoke a new page request with these parameter? The only solution i see there is to write your own datatable component with such a sorting and pagination. But I am really curious if I am the first person having this issue. From my point of view this is feature that should be handled by a component framework.

Comment: @fischermatte I just don't use the Primefaces paginator. Just add the links I coded for you wherever you want them and apply the styles you want.  I also don't use the LazyDataModel that Primefaces has.  I consider it a waste of time.  Instead I just have a property based on List<myobjclass>.  It will generate a list of the data based on the other properties in the backing bean.

Comment: thx alan. dont know, of course i could code everything on my own. but this feels kind of wrong. for this reason i use a component lib like primefaces.

Comment: sorry for accepting your answer late. at the moment I see this is the only reasonable approach. but I am supprised that the ajax / browser back issue is not handled in a proper way in recent JSF component libs like primefaces.

Comment: No problems.   Keep in mind that JSF and Primefaces -- all the component libraries actually -- are evolving.  Different people have different coding practices and I think mine are more exacting than theirs.  They probably think the same thing. ;)